# How does Einstein STO handle unengaged users?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein-analytics, einstein

If any of you have experience with Einstein STO, how does it handle the unengaged users?

Is there a way to see these users within SFMC tool upon deployment?

Also, is there a way to control scheduling/sending these groups of users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question: Is there a way to see these users within SFMC tool upon deployment?**

**Answer:**
You can see aggregated data on the STO dashboard and search individual Contact IDs, but you cannot currently see any type of list of users that are unassigned to an optimal send time ("pending"). I also cannot see any data extension with the raw data like for Einstein Engagement Frequency or Engagement Splits.

[image]

**Question: is there a way to control scheduling/sending these groups of users?**

**Answer:** You can just check the Journey Builder STO event which refers to two options for this.

"When Einstein doesn't have enough data, messages send according to the Insufficient Data Options specified in Einstein in Setup."

Setup / Einstein / Send Time Optimization :

"Insufficient Data Options:
Select a send time for when Einstein doesn't have enough data about a contact to make a prediction.

a) Send at Einstein's optimal default time:

[image]

b) Send immediately"

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Appreciate it!


Regarding not seeing a list of users that are unassigned to STO and only seeing contact IDs by individual emails, not that best, but its something for the time being.


About the handling of unengaged users, yes, I did have a look at this section and assume this is the only avenue to follow right now. It does give insights.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as accepted :)